# How to add elements to Hash in one line?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with some data inside. I want to add more elements into it, in one line, for simplicity. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
hash = add_items_to_it(hash, { alpha: 1, beta: 2 })
```

Is it possible?

Comment: hash.merge!({ alpha: 1, beta: 2 })..

Comment: Don't tie yourself to doing it in one line. Instead, as you write your code, observe the code as if you were seeing it for the first time, and write it in the most-clear manor you can. Do that even with code you think is only prototype, as too often prototype code gets pushed into production and someone else eventually has to maintain it.

Comment: Just replace all linebreaks with semicolons. Boom. All your code in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Hash#merge!`

```
hash.merge! { alpha: 1, beta: 2 }
```

Read documentation :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ri Hash#merge!

= Hash#merge!

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hsh.merge!(other_hash)                                 -> hsh
  hsh.merge!(other_hash){|key, oldval, newval| block}    -> hsh

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Adds the contents of other_hash to hsh.  If no block
is specified, entries with duplicate keys are overwritten with the values from
other_hash, otherwise the value of each duplicate key is
determined by calling the block with the key, its value in hsh and its
value in other_hash.

  h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
  h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
  h1.merge!(h2)   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}

  h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
  h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
  h1.merge!(h2) { |key, v1, v2| v1 }
                  #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}


lines 1-25/25 (END)
```

Comment: ri? What, you don't have internet or something? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No.. I sometimes don't..hehehehe :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Hash#merge`:

```
hash = { one: 1, two: 2 }
#=> {:one=>1, :two=>2}
hash = hash.merge({ alpha: 1, beta: 2 })
#=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :alpha=>1, :beta=>2}
```

Comment: It will create a new `Hash` FYI.

Comment: Yes. There is an another method `merge!` to replace the hash, but you already mentioned it :)